# PHP Agregar elemento Array

Tags: php

```
$conexion2 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ProbandoMysql');

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM persona";


  if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion2, $consulta)) {

        /* obtener el array por índices */
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $array [] = $fila; 
        }
```

print_r($array);

```
        foreach ($array as $k=>$v){
        echo $k." - ".$v;
    }
```

Me muestra el html:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [dni] => 1a [nombre] => edu [edad] => 22 ) [1] => Array ( [dni] => 1b [nombre] => diego [edad] => 30 ) [2] => Array ( [dni] => 3f [nombre] => carlos [edad] => 11 ) )

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MysqlProce\verarray.php on line 55
0 - Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MysqlProce\verarray.php on line 55
1 - Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MysqlProce\verarray.php on line 55
2 - Array
```

Comment: Claro, porque aquí: `while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {` estás trayendo una sola fila (row)... debes cambiarlo por fetch simplemente: **`while ($fila = mysqli_fetch($resultado)) {`**

Comment: También podrías usar un `for` y acceder a tu `array` de la siguiente forma  `for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) { echo $array[$i]['nombre']; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es que al hacerlo así:

```
$array= array("Dni" => $fila[0],"Nombre"=> $fila[1],"edad"=> $fila[2]."\n");
```

Estás reemplazando el valor de array en cada pasada del bucle.

Tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
$array []= array("Dni" => $fila[0],"Nombre"=> $fila[1],"edad"=> $fila[2]);
```

La `\n\` no tiene ningún sentido en el array.

Tampoco hace falta declarar la variable `$array` al principio, aunque es mejor hacerlo por buena costumbre de programación, pues en eso PHP es muy permisivo. Desde la versión 7 han empezado a restringir ciertas cosas.

Aunque la mejor manera de hacer esto es con [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) que crea un array asociativo cuyas claves son los nombres de columna. De esa manera pasas directamente cada fila al array sin tener que escribir los nombres de clave manualmente.

Ejemplo:

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion2, $consulta)) {

    /* obtener el array por índices */
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
       $array []= $fila; 
    }
    /*Aquí puedes ver tu resultado*/
    print_r ($array); //La salida aquí es sólo para depurar.
}
```

---

Si quieres mostrar algún dato en pantalla dentro del mismo `while`, lo podrás hacer mediante `$fila["nombre-columna"]`, por ejemplo:

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion2, $consulta)) {

    /* obtener el array por índices */
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
       echo "DNI: ".$fila["dni"]."\n";
       echo "Nombre: ".$fila["nombre"]."\n";
       echo "Edad: ".$fila["edad"]."\n";

    }
}
```

---

Si quieres leerlo fuera del `while` mostrando la clave y al lado el valor:

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion2, $consulta)) {
$array=array();
    /* obtener el array por índices */
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
       $array []= $fila; //La declaración de $array arriba no es necesaria
    }

    /*Aquí puedes ver tu resultado*/
    foreach ($array as $k=>$v){
        if (is_array($v)){
            foreach ($v as $kk=>$vv){
                echo $kk." - ".$vv."\n";
            }

         }else{

            echo $k." - ".$v;
         }
    }

}
```

---

O, si sólo te interesan los valores, puedes usar un solo bucle (lee comentario en el código):

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion2, $consulta)) {
    $array=array();
    /* obtener el array por índices */
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
       $array []= $fila; //La declaración de $array arriba no es necesaria
    }

    /*
       Aquí puedes ver tu resultado
       Esto es interesante cuando no se requiere mostrar
       los datos de una vez, sino en otro sitio,
       pasándolos a otro función por ejemplo
       Se cierran todos los recursos de base de datos
       y la información queda en el array para uso posterior
    */
    foreach ($array as $persona){
        echo $persona["dni"]."  ".$persona["nombre"]." ".$persona["edad"].\n";
    }
}
```

---

O, como bien ha comentado @D.Bulten, puedes leerlo con un blucle `for`:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) { 
    echo $array[$i]['dni']."\n"; 
    echo $array[$i]['nombre']."\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Perfecto pero me da el formato feo :
Array ( [0] => Array ( [dni] => 1a [nombre] => edu [edad] => 22 ) [1] => Array ( [dni] => 1b [nombre] => diego [edad] => 30 ) [2] => Array ( [dni] => 3f [nombre] => carlos [edad] => 11 ) )

Entiendo que ha creado un Array de Arrays ¿ pero para acceder ?
Yo quiero que en cada pasada del for diga dni ->edu,edad->22 ... y así 
Porque el formate ese no me es viable...

 foreach ($cad as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ": " . $value . " ";
}

Comment: Je je nooo, es que el `print_r` sale así. Eso es para depuración, para probar que el código funciona. Si quieres salida en pantalla inmediata puedes hacerlo dentro del `while` o fuera. Ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Al hacer el bucle del foreach($array as key => value) ......

Me saca el error:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MysqlProce\verarray.php on line 40
0: Array 
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MysqlProce\verarray.php on line 40
1: Array 
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MysqlProce\verarray.php on line 40
2: Array

Comment: Lee la respuesta editada @EduBw y recuerda quitar esta declaración de arriba: `$array = array();` quizá por eso te está creando un array de arrays. Si no funciona haz un `print_r ($array);` y comparte el resultado... pero quitando esa declaración inicial que te menciono, debería funcionar sin problema.

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MysqlProce\verarray.php

Gracias por tu tiempo !
  


  <pre>  if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion2, $consulta)) {

        /* obtener el array por índices */
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $array [] = $fila; //La declaración de $array arriba no es necesaria
        }

        foreach ($array as $k=>$v){
        echo $k." - ".$v;
        return $array;
    }</pre>

Comment: @EduBw por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/113088/edit) poniendo el código como lo tienes actualmente y si puedes poniendo el resultado del `print_r`. Es muy extraño que no funcione así.

Comment: Ya está editada la pregunta tal cual tengo el código y lo que muestra el html, muchas gracias, ando perdido ...

Comment: Efectivamente @EduBw se crea un array de arrays y no entiendo por qué. Yo estoy acostumbrado a usar este método en PDO y funciona bien. Edité la respuesta. En el último código muestro cómo leer el array de arrays. Funciona, pero no es lo que quería... haré pruebas con otros tipos de fetch a ver qué pasa y propondré una mejor solución si la encuentro.

Comment: Bueno, por lo menos sé que funciona ver la BBDD xD.
Valoro mucho tu interés y tu ayuda =)

Comment: Buen aporte @A.Cedano , 1+.