# convertir resultado sql en array bidimensional en php

Tags: php, sql, array

Quiero meter los resultados de una consulta sql en un array bidimesional.
La tabla sería algo asi como id ->1 nombre -> pepe apellidos-> garcia y otros campos ...
y quiero que lo meta en array bidimensional array[indice]['mismo nombre que el campo de la tabla'].
He logrado hacerlo como viene abajo pero son demasiados campos como para meterlos a mano y, además, estoy seguro que debe haber otra forma.

```
    <?php
include "conexion.php";

$consulta="SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE nombre like 'Juan';";
$resultado=$conexion->query($consulta) or die("No puedo realizar la consulta");
$i=0;
while ($array=$resultado->fetch_array()){
$arrayauxliar[$i]['id']=$array['id'];
$arrayauxliar[$i]['nombre']=$array['nombre'];
/*aqui vendrían un churro de campos*/
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Sería bueno que indiques si estás usando PDO o Mysqli. Ambos tienen el método fetch_assoc que crea a partir de los resultados un array asociativo cuyas claves son los nombres de columna de la tabla y los valores son los datos respectivos a cada, columna. Hace poco respondí una pregunta parecida a la tuya pero por estar desde el teléfono se me dificulta indicarte el enlace.

Comment: Estoy utilizando mysqli, la respuesta que ha publicado Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas funciona pero creo que tiene que haber otra manera más fácil que se me escapa. Yo usaba la clase adodb para la consultas sql que hacía o hace(la última vez que la probé en php 7 no iba) lo que pido. Lo que quiero es hacerlo con las clases que trae php por defecto.

Comment: [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113094/29967). En los comentarios se ha debatido un poco sobre el tema. Es relativamente fácil almacenar el resultado en un array, sólo que por motivos que no acabo de entender, mysqli crea un array de arrays, por lo que hay que leerlo usando dos bulces for anidados o de la forma explicada al final de la respuesta. Creo que es una forma más clara y simple de hacer las cosas. A mi por esto y por otras cosas más, me gusta usar PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener las claves del arreglo devuelto por la consulta y de esa manera podrás asignarle automáticamente el índice de acorde a su nombre que serían los atributos de tu tabla

```
<?php
    include "conexion.php";

    $consulta="SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE nombre like 'Juan';";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($consulta) or die("No puedo realizar la consulta");
    $i=0;
    while ($array=$resultado->fetch_array()){
        //Obtengo las claves del arreglo que en tu caso son los atributos de la tabla (id, nombre, etc)
        $claves = array_keys($array);
        //Recorro el arreglo de las claves para ir asignando los datos al arreglo con los nombres de los atributos
        foreach($claves as $clave){
            $arrayauxliar[$i][$clave]=$array[$clave];
        }           
        $i++;
    }
```