# ¿Porque mi código php me devuelve valores numéricos en lugar de los que yo le di en un principio?

Tags: php

Tengo un código en php para conectar con mi base de datos para luego usar un objeto Json en mi proyecto. El código funciona pero da las respuestas de manera extraña. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oftalmogestion_2_vot");

    $us_usuario = $_POST['us_usuario'];
    $us_clave = $_POST['us_clave'];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT U.us_usuario, U.us_clave, A.hora_inicio, A.hora_fin, A.fecha, A.nombre, A.apellidos, A.prestacion FROM td_agenda_envision A, td_usuario U WHERE U.us_clave = ? AND U.us_usuario = ? AND U.us_ag_alias !='' AND A.id_usuario = U.us_idUsuario");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'ss', $us_usuario, $us_clave);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $us_usuario, $us_clave, $hora_inicio, $hora_fin, $fecha, $nombre, $apellidos, $prestacion);

        $arrRespuesta = array();
        $response['success'] = false;

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['success'] = true);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['us_usuario'] = $us_usuario);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['us_clave'] = $us_clave);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['nombre'] = $nombre);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['apellidos'] = $apellidos);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['hora_inicio'] = $hora_inicio);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['hora_fin'] = $hora_fin);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['fecha'] = $fecha);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['prestacion'] = $prestacion);
        }

echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);
?>
```

Y el resultado que me da en el Json es este, para Usuario ALICIA y clave ALICIA

```
{
    "0": true,
    "1": "ALICIA",
    "2": "ALICIA",
    "3": "DOLORES",
    "4": "GARCIA DE LEON",
    "5": "17:20",
    "6": "17:35",
    "7": "2013-10-09",
    "8": "TOMOGRAFIA DE COHERENCIA OPTICA (OCT)",
    "9": true,
    "10": "ALICIA",
    "11": "ALICIA",
    "12": "ANABEL",
    "13": "RUIZ CASADO",
    "14": "10:00",
    "15": "10:15",
    "16": "2013-10-14",
    "17": "CONSULTA OFTALMOLOGICA",
    "success": true,
    "us_usuario": "ALICIA",
    "us_clave": "ALICIA",
    "nombre": "ANABEL",
    "apellidos": "RUIZ CASADO",
    "hora_inicio": "10:00",
    "hora_fin": "10:15",
    "fecha": "2013-10-14",
    "prestacion": "CONSULTA OFTALMOLOGICA"
}
```

¿Alguna idea de porqué me salen primero las respuestas como 1, 2, 3, 4... y luego me salen con los valores que yo les di en un principio?

Comment: Cuantos resultados devuelve la SQL?

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `array_push()` en lugar de directamente `$arrRespueta['bla']='ble'`?

Comment: La consulta me devuelve 2 resultados(si te fijas del 9 al 17 son los mismos resultados que desde success hasta prestacion), y uso array_push porque de la otra forma los resultados se machacan al final, dandome sólo un resultado.

Comment: Esto es lo que me devuelve si sólo tengo $arrRespuesta['bla']=''ble
    {
    "success": true,
    "us_usuario": "ALICIA",
    "us_clave": "ALICIA",
    "nombre": "ANABEL",
    "apellidos": "RUIZ CASADO",
    "hora_inicio": "10:00",
    "hora_fin": "10:15",
    "fecha": "2013-10-14",
    "prestacion": "CONSULTA OFTALMOLOGICA"
    }

Comment: Tu caso es [muy parecido a este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113094/29967)... en realidad no necesitas `array_push`. Puedes llenar el array con las claves-valores dentro del bucle. El problema es que mysqli por motivos que desconozco, te crea un array de arrays... bueno, tampoco es tanto problema, sólo que tienes que usar dos bucles `for` para leer o bien leerlo como se indica al final de la respuesta.

Comment: Prueba simplemente esto: **`while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
       $arrRespuesta []= $fila; //La declaración de $arrRespuesta arriba, antes del while no es necesaria
    } echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);`**

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: arrRespuesta in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 17

Me dan estos dos errores con esos cambios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es para mí una de las peores limitaciones de `mysqli` con respecto a PDO.

Si tú tienes el driver mysqlnd instalado el proceso podría ser sencillo... pero siempre el código quedaría limitado a tener ese driver y si lo corres en un servidor que no lo tenga el código fallará.

De hecho, yo plantee una pregunta ayer en este sentido: [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967). La respuesta de @D.Bulten  dio en el clavo.

Necesitarás entonces implementar una función que haga lo que hace `FETCHASSOC` en PDO, o lo que hace mysqli cuando el driver referido más arriba está instalado.

La función es la siguiente, y la puedes tener en una clase donde almacenes código auxiliar, de ese modo no tienes que repetirla cada vez que la necesites... Si te quieres evitar todo este lío puedes también pasarte a PDO y te olvidas de esto.

### Función

Esta es la función:

```
function get_result( $Statement ) {
    $RESULT = array();
    $Statement->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
        $PARAMS = array();
        while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
        $Statement->fetch();
    }
    return $RESULT;
}
```

---

### Modo de uso

En vez del while así:

```
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['success'] = true);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['us_usuario'] = $us_usuario);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['us_clave'] = $us_clave);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['nombre'] = $nombre);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['apellidos'] = $apellidos);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['hora_inicio'] = $hora_inicio);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['hora_fin'] = $hora_fin);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['fecha'] = $fecha);
        array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['prestacion'] = $prestacion);
    }
```

Haces simplemente esto:

```
$arrRespuesta = get_result($statement);
echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);
```

En una prueba de concepto, mi resultado fue este:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Los Miserables"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Un hombre para la  eternidad"
}]
```

Nótese que crea un JSON Array, no un objeto JSON... pero es casi lo mismo.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias.